# Send As Distribution Group in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I've created a couple of distribution groups for our organization, and we'd like to start using these distribution addresses as our outgoing address (for things like support) rather than our personal email addresses.

To test, I've added "Send As" to myself for our support group, but I'm having some issues sending email.

- If I manually type in our support email address (which is set as the primary [and only] email address for the DG) and send the email, I get the "You can't send a message on behalf of this user..." message from the postmaster and the email does not go out.
- If I select the DG by clicking on "From..." and browsing the address book, then it works fine. Curiously, the DG does not show up in the GAL, but if I go to "All Groups", it appears
- If I try to send another email by clicking on the entry that shows up in the "From" popup now, it fails again.

I'm willing to live with having to select the DG from the address book the *first* time, but having to browse to it every time is going to become tedious. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in cached mode try coming out of cached mode and look in the GAL for the DG.

Comment: This, oddly enough, fixed it (or, rather made the groups show up in the GAL, which allowed me to send repeated messages). Switching back unfortunately takes it out; what do I need to do to fix this completely?

Comment: Once your OAB is updated overnight (if you have the default update time of 5am) you should be fine.

Comment: I tried forcing an update, but it did not appear to affect anything.

Comment: Forcing an OAB update on the server doesn't immediately take affect especially if you have a large OAB.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your OAB hasn't updated to the client with the DG.  Force an OAB update on the server and the client and try it again.  The fact that the DG doesn't show in the GAL is usually indicative of an OAB mismatch.

Comment: I've forced an update to the OAB through EMC on the server and through Outlook on the client. No dice, unfortunately. Would this have an effect upon my ability to send from the address more than once, as I described?

Comment: Have you tested a normal user and configure the permissions the same way?  Does the same issue occur then?

Comment: I haven't tried another user yet, but I did just try changing a different DG. This DG *does* show up in the GAL (it's an older DG, whereas the one I've been testing with is brand new and I'm the only member) and appears to work fine.

Comment: I'd start looking at your environment and make sure that your OAB updates are occuring.  If you have a semi-complex environment it might be getting stuck somewhere.  Barring that, double check permissions as well because I think EX2010 does send as vs. full mailbox control differently than at least 2003 (not sure about 2007).  Also test with a normal user and see if you can reproduce.

Comment: @Holocryptic: Our environment is very simple: one Exchange 2010 server that handles all roles, and just a few workstations that connect to it.

Comment: Do you see an sync errors on the client?

Comment: No, no sync errors. I'm seeing that all of our *existing* groups show up in the GAL, but none of the ones I've created today. I've updated the OAB again on the server (and the properties window shows the right modification date) and I've updated it on the client (Send / Receive -> Send/Receive Groups -> Download Address Book...) but no dice.

Comment: Yeah, there's something hinky going on with your OAB updates.  I'm running a little out of ideas, and I don't have Ex2010 in my organization.  Start going through your logs on the server and client and try to isolate why your OAB isn't updating.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, though it looks like @Cheekaleak's solution is at least a temporary fix (turning off Cached Exchange Mode corrected the behavior, though I'd prefer not to be forced into that)

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you need to create Mail-enabled Security group (Scope = Univesal)

Comment: This may have been true of previous versions of Exchange (I can't say one way or the other), but this does not appear to be true of 2010.